# why I still don't get an empty array?

Tags: php, arrays

Quoted from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

> If delimiter contains a value that is
>   not contained in string and a negative
>   limit is used, then an empty array
>   will be returned, otherwise an array
>   containing string will be returned.

But why I still don't get an empty array?

```
var_dump(explode(',', '', -1))
```

I get this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

**UPDATE**

Try it in windows,with PHP 5.2.8 (cli) (built: Dec  8 2008 19:31:23)

Comment: What *do* you get?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running that on?

Comment: PHP 5.2.8 (cli) (built: Dec  8 2008 19:31:23)

Comment: why you are looking for empty array from such a expression? there is an easy way- `$arr=array();`

Comment: I'm not looking for empty array,just spot a bug-alike stuff

Comment: I see this happen only in php versions older than 5.1.0, which was when negative limits were added.  Can't reproduce what you see with 5.2.13 (I haven't checked 5.2.8.)

Comment: @bluesmoon - I'm able to reproduce it on 5.1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that this doesn't work in `PHP 5.2.8`.

It does work in `PHP 5.2.11`. In my opinion, there are many bugs in the 5.2 branch, so try always to use the latest version. 5.3 is more stable in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this example and got empty array. Wrong question.

Comment: Trurl, it results
`array(1) { [0]=>  string(0) "" }`
which is non-empty

Comment: Please use latest PHP version. May be this is a bug

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code, and it does return an empty array: `array(0) { }`.
Running PHP 5.2.11.

Maybe there's an issue with your PHP version. Can you tell us which one you are running?